# Delete items older than a day - SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, datetime

In a table in my datatase I have a datatime column which stores the time at which the record is added. How can I delete all records which are older than a day when I run a stored procedure (considering the current time) ?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

You can build a DELETE statement making use of the [datediff](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa258269%28SQL.80%29.aspx) and the [getdate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188383.aspx) functions.

Usage example:

```
DELETE FROM yourTable WHERE DATEDIFF(day,getdate(),thatColumn) < -1
```

Comment: You got this backwards. Based on the question, "thatColumn" will always be in the past, and the way you wrote this, your DATEDIFF will always be greater than 0.
Correct way is: "DELETE FROM yourTable WHERE DATEDIFF(day,getdate(),thatColumn) < -1"
Or: "DELETE FROM yourTable WHERE DATEDIFF(day,thatColumn,getdate()) > 1"

Answer (score 30):

When it comes to SQL, you have to specify what you mean by "older than a day".

- DATEDIFF: it uses day boundary midnight so run it at 19th October 00:05 and you'll delete rows 6 minutes old (18th October 23:59)
- 24 hours?
- Yesterday midnight? Run code on 19th October, delete rows before 18th?

Also, don't put a function on a column.

This assumes 24 hours to the minute:

```
DELETE
    MyTableWhere
WHERE
    MyColumn < DATEADD(day, -1, GETDATE())
```

This assumes *yesterday* midnight:

```
DELETE
    MyTableWhere
WHERE
    MyColumn < DATEADD(DAY, DATEDIFF(DAY, 0, GETDATE()), -1)
```

Answer (score 5):

```
Delete <TableName>
Where DATEDIFF(day, <ColumnName>, getdate()) > 0
```

Raj

Comment: you might have forgot a 'FROM' ;)

Comment: From is not required with a delete statement :)

Comment: Weird casing with those keywords.

Answer (score 0):

I generally advise against actually deleting data from your database because you never know when you may need to go back and recover or rollback to previous records because of data corruption or an audit, etc. Instead I would add an bit column title something like "IsDeleted" and set day old entries to true using an update statement.

Something like

```
'UPDATE tablename SET IsDeleted = 1 WHERE (DATEDIFF(day,DateCreatedOn,GETDATE()) > 0)
```

Where DateCreatedOn is where your record's created on or timestamp date would go

Comment: This is a tough generalization without knowing the problem set.  There are as many good reasons to delete data as  not.  If you need to rollback or recover, that's why you have backups.  If the standard operation of your app means you no longer need the data, then delete the data.

Comment: If you never delete data, eventually--inevitably--overcrowded tables will lead to degraded performance. If you must keep the data "hot", copying it to an archive table and then deleting from the source, perhaps after hours, should be a viable option.

Comment: I'll admit it's a bit over zealous, but it's better to have it and not need it, then not have it and need it. 
Imagine the kind of response you would get from a client who says they need all sales records from their e-Commerce application for the past 5 years and your response to them is "We deleted it because it was old and not currently needed by the application".

Just because the application itself might not need the data, it doesn't mean that the client doesn't need it and can do without either.

Comment: An overlooked design criteria I picked up long ago is: for every fact (table, column, whatever), identify it's lifetime -- when can it be removed, deleted, forgotten. That way you'd know the *client* needs the data for five years. (Applications need performance, clients need data, and implementations need to support both.)

Comment: @Philip, I agree with your last statement, and looking over my answer again, I can see why you are stressing your point of view.

All I wanted to get across with my answer is the "delete forever" notion this question brought up. Certainly I see no problem in moving "old" data from a production table to some sort of archive for increased performance. I just believe that no data should be physically deleted without some means of recovering it.

Comment: archiving data is a better option than running an update, especially when you are dealing with millions of rows. I try to stay away from updates in these cases.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming date column to be "RecordCreatedDate"

DELETE FROM yourtable WHERE RecordCreatedDate < DATEADD(d, -1, GETDATE())

I only caution that if your database has millions of rows your should have an index on the RecordCreatedDate column and possibly do smaller batch deletes if you will be removing large amounts of data.

Answer (score 0):

delete from YourTable where DateColumn < getdate()-1

Answer (score -1):

or

> ts >= now() - INTERVAL 1 DAY

where ts is a name of the datetime column

Comment: Yes it does. At least on MySQL.

Comment: @Zepplock MySQL is not SQL Server. SQL Server is a product name of a relational database system from Microsoft.